# How to retain sliderInput range of a variable(s) when additional variables added dynamically?

Tags: dynamic, slider, shiny, render

The following code allows to create `sliderInput` control widgets for selected number of variables. For the brevity, filtering code as per sliderInput range is removed. So, please neglect what is being seen in the data table.
 `sliderInput` widgets pop up whenever a new variable selected or added to the list of already existing variables. However, these widgets do not retain the previously selected values, i.e., let's say you selected `sepal.length`, modified slider range, and then selected `sepal.width`. We'll have two widgets but widget of `sepal.length` does not retain the modified values, i.e., the slider falls back to the original values. Agreed that retaining modified values is not being coded, and I'm unable to figure it out how it can be done. 
 I understand that I need to read `sliderInput` range values as soon as they modified, save new modified values, and then update `sliderInput` range with the saved values before the list of functions called in `renderUI`. And, the other way is read new values as global variable and use them while creating in widgets, but I plan to access the control widgets in other tabs, so, this does not appear to be a neat idea. Greatly appreciate suggestions.

```
# Create a data frame of which information is used in creating (dynamical) control widgets
varnames <- names(iris[,1:4]) # names
varinit <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,median) # initival value used in slider
varmin <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,min) # min.
varmax <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,max) # max. 

ui <- navbarPage(
   tabPanel("Plot",
            sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                  checkboxGroupInput("ConditioningVariables", "Conditioning variables (choose one or more):",
                                     varnames,inline = TRUE),
                  uiOutput("ControlWidgetsofConditioningVariables")  
               ),
               mainPanel(
                  dataTableOutput("data")
               )
               )
            )
   )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   allControls <- lapply(setNames(varnames, varnames), function(x) {

                sliderInput(x, x, varmin[x], varmax[x], c(varmin[x], varinit[x]), 
                  round = -2)   
   })
   output$ControlWidgetsofConditioningVariables <- renderUI({    
      if (is.null(input$ConditioningVariables)){
         return() 
      } else {
         allControls[input$ConditioningVariables]
      }
   })
   ## filtering related code is removed, so, data does not change ...
   newdata <- reactive({
         iris
   })
   output$data <- renderDataTable({ newdata() })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Instead of using `renderUI` which re-renders all your controls, try `insertUI` in Shiny 0.14.

Comment: Great feature, thanks. However, I'm still trying to figure out how can I use it. i.e., let's say we selected `sepal.length`, modified slider range, and then selected sepal.width. Now, we'll have three,_not two_, widgets. As it mentioned in the website, `insertUI` creates new objects in addition to the ones already there (all independent from one another), therefore, I need to create a customized (or reactive) function to track newly added variables, which will be passed into the `insertUI`, and deselected variables passed into to the `removeUI`. Struck here, and greatly appreciate leads.

Comment: You just need a global variable that holds the list of variables selected. Then you can compare this global variable with `input$ConditioningVariables` and add or remove UI depending on which one is longer (contains more items).

Comment: @warmoverflow Neat suggestion. Now, `insertUI` inserts widgets but `removeUI` is not working. I tried a few jQuery options (`id` & `.class`) for `selector` in the `removeUI` but no success yet. Here are key commands: `insertUI(
      ui = allControls[setdiff(input$ConditioningVariables,ListofSelVars)]
   ); ListofSelVars <<- input$ConditioningVariables`  `setdiff(ListofSelVars,input$ConditioningVariables)` gives names of elements to be removed, and `removeUI(
            selector = paste0("#",setdiff(ListofSelVars,input$ConditioningVariables))
         )` should work but not working

Comment: ID itself won't work. As suggested by Shiny documentation, the easiest way is to wrap your selectInput with a named div `tags$div(id="wrapper_id", sliderInput...)`, and then you can remove it using `#wrapper_id`

Comment: It is my lack of HTML/CSS knowledge, but is it possible to assign a specific id for each variable when multiple variables are selected via `input$ConditioningVariables`. Greatly appreciate leads. Thanks

Comment: You can just name each `tags$div` after the corresponding `slideInput`. So for example `tags$div(id="sepal.width.div", sliderInput("sepal.width.slider", ...))`. I'll create an example when I get more time.

Comment: Look forward for it, however, created [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457622/removing-multiple-elements-with-removeui-wrapping-multiple-elements-with-tags). Code might come little handy when you create an example.