# Removing multiple elements with removeUI / wrapping multiple elements with tags$div() assigning an id for each variable

Tags: html, css, dynamic, widget, shiny

I was suggested using `insertUI` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430899/how-to-retain-sliderinput-range-of-a-variables-when-additional-variables-added?noredirect=1#comment68153429_40430899) and found that it is a great feature. The following code allows to generate control widgets for a single or multiple elements using `insertUI`, but struck on incorporating `removeUI` related part. Tried `jQuery` options to remove inserted UI elements but did not work out. I found the following from [Shiny dynamic UI](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html), i.e., *Note that, if you are inserting multiple elements in one call, you must wrap them in either a tagList() or a tags$div() (the latter option has the advantage that you can give it an id to make it easier to reference or remove it later on)*. Also, [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430899/how-to-retain-sliderinput-range-of-a-variables-when-additional-variables-added?noredirect=1#comment68153429_40430899)  gave some clues, i.e., `tags$div(id="sepal.width.div", sliderInput("sepal.width.slider", ...))`, but my lack of `HTML`/`CSS` knowledge stops me going forward. I'm looking at (a) wrapping multiple widget element(s) with tags$div() assigning a unique id for each variable, which will be used in `removeUI`; (b) calling multiple elements via `removeUI`.

```
varnames <- names(iris[,1:4]) # names
varinit <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,median) # initival value used in slider
varmin <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,min) # min.
varmax <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,max) # max. 

ListofSelVars <<- vector(mode="character")

# control widgets for all elements
allControls <- lapply(setNames(varnames, varnames), function(x) {

   sliderInput(x, x, varmin[x], varmax[x], c(varmin[x], varinit[x]), 
               round = -2)   
})

ui <- navbarPage(
   tabPanel("Plot",
            sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                  checkboxGroupInput("ConditioningVariables", "Conditioning variables (choose one or more):",
                                     varnames,inline = TRUE),
                  # add an action button
                  actionButton("add", "Update UI elements")
               ),
               mainPanel()
            )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$add, {
      insertUI(
         selector ='#add',
         where = "afterEnd",
         ui = allControls[setdiff(input$ConditioningVariables,ListofSelVars)]
      )

      ## removeUI related goes, here
      ## removeUI(selector=paste0())
      ## setdiff(ListofSelVars,input$ConditioningVariables) gives elements to be removed

      ## Global variable, keep track of elements that are selected

      ListofSelVars <<- input$ConditioningVariables

   })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code. The main issue is with the names here, i.e. `Sepal.Width`. I wrapped each slider with a div with id like `div.Sepal.Width` so that it is easier to remove. `removeUI` requires a jQuery selector, so it appears that something like `#div.Sepal.Width` would work, except that it does not, because `.` is itself a jQuery selector that means `class`, so we need to double escape the `.`. Of course you can also remove the `.` when you first create the divs, thus avoiding the trouble...

```
varnames <- names(iris[,1:4]) # names
varinit <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,median) # initival value used in slider
varmin <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,min) # min.
varmax <- apply(iris[,1:4],2,max) # max. 

ListofSelVars <<- vector(mode="character")

# control widgets for all elements
allControls <- lapply(setNames(varnames, varnames), function(x) {
  tags$div(id=paste0("div.",x), sliderInput(x, x, varmin[x], varmax[x], c(varmin[x], varinit[x]), 
              round = -2))
})

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Dynamic sliders"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("ConditioningVariables", "Conditioning variables (choose one or more):",
                         varnames,inline = TRUE),
      # add an action button
      actionButton("add", "Update UI elements")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plot_out")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$add, {

    insertUI(
      selector ='#add',
      where = "afterEnd",
      ui = allControls[setdiff(input$ConditioningVariables,ListofSelVars)]
    )

    ListofRemoval <- setdiff(ListofSelVars,input$ConditioningVariables)

    for (item in ListofRemoval) {
      item = gsub(".", "\\.", item, fixed=TRUE)
      item = paste0("#div\\.", item)
      removeUI(item)
    }

    ListofSelVars <<- input$ConditioningVariables

  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Explanation particularly about `jQuery` selector and using double escape comes handy if I want to modify div id. Great.